# Group_concat - laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, group-concat

please I want to use group_concat in a query using eloquent and not raw queries.

here is the code which i tried to execute and did't work for me:

```
commands::join('products', 'products.id', '=','commands.idproduct')
->select('commands.username','**group_concat(products.name)**')
->group by ('commands. username')
->get();
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try using DB::raw() to wrap 'raw' SQL you want in a query: `->select('commands.username',DB::raw('group_concat(products.name)'))`

Comment: thanks for your reply @alexrussell but the problem is that when I add the DB::raw  and I run again the application I get this error: 
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'Storage\Commands\DB' not found

Comment: Ahh you're in a namespace - either add `use DB;` after your namespace declaration or use `DB` in your code: `\DB::raw('group_concat(products.name)')`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just used:

`use DB;`

and in my query I used

`DB::raw('group_concat(products.name)')`

Comment: You should mark this answer as the correct answer so that people know.

Answer (score 6):

Best example for it..

```
 
ModelName::select('ID', DB::raw('CONCAT(First_Name, " ", Last_Name) AS full_name'))
           ->get()
           ->toArray();

Result 
   Jon Doe,Jeffery Way,Tailer,taylor otwell
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me

```
$list = TableName::where('user_id', 'user_001'
        ->groupBy('user_id')
        ->groupBy('subscription_id')
        ->select('user_id','subscription_id','type')
        ->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(holiday) as holidays')
        ->get();
```

or

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$sql = 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(holiday) as holidays, user_id,subscription_id, type FROM TableName 
        where vendor_id = 'user_001' GROUP BY user_id, subscription_id;';
$list = DB::select($sql, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

or just replace

```
->select('commands.username','**group_concat(products.name)**')
```

with

```
->selectRaw('commands.username, **group_concat(products.name)**')
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: (9.0+)

```
DB::raw('string_agg(products.name, \',\') as products')
```

You will need to use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; for this.

Answer (score -3):

$data=\DB::table('paging_config')
            ->leftjoin('paging_groups', 'paging_config.page_group', '=', 'paging_groups.page_number')
            ->leftjoin('spk_mnt', 'paging_groups.ext', '=', 'spk_mnt.stn_no')
            ->select('paging_config.page_group','paging_groups.ext', 'spk_mnt.stn_status')
            ->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT description) as description')
            ->where('paging_config.page_group','=','paging_config.page_group')
            ->groupBy('paging_config.description')

```
        ->get();
```