# Laravel Query using GroupBy with distinct traits

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Trying to figure out how I can display results for a database that has data like this...

If the data is stored like this...

```
 Style              Color
```

1. Classy Hat         - Red
2. Classy Hat         - Blue
3. Classy Hat         - Yellow
4. Stylish Hat        - Red
5. Stylish Hat        - Blue
6. Clean Hat          - Black

If I want to show the data like this

### Classy Hat

Colors: Red, Blue, Yellow

### Stylish Hat

Colors: Red, Blue

### Clean Hat

Colors: Black

I cant figure out how to simultaneously group by as well as show the distinct traits within the group.  I see examples of how to show the count of each distinct, but not how to display unique trait values for grouped records.

Comment: 1) paste if you have try some code, 
2) you may to see documentation in this section:https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships and this post maybe can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847738/group-concat-laravel-eloquent

Comment: The code I could paste wouldnt help much because its behaving as expected for a groupBy query.  I was able to achieve this in other languages by writing a loop within a loop IE.  Outer loop identified the grouped style and inner loop queried for the unique ID's but I cant figure out how to do the same in laravel since its all modulated and processed before display.  The relationship doesnt work because its all in one table, not a relationship to a different table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just fetch a normal collection from the modal, ie. `Styles::all()`. Then use the `groupBy` function on the collection.

```
// Sample data as per database query
$data = collect([
    ['style' => 'classy hat', 'color' => 'red'],
    ['style' => 'classy hat', 'color' => 'orange'],
    ['style' => 'classy hat', 'color' => 'green'],
    ['style' => 'stylish hat', 'color' => 'blue'],
    ['style' => 'stylish hat', 'color' => 'orange'],
]);

$styles = $data->groupBy('style');

foreach ($styles as $style => $colors) {
    echo "<h1>" . $style . "</h1>";
    echo implode(', ', $colors->pluck('color')->toArray());
}
```

That would give you

**classy hat**

red, orange, green

**stylish hat**

blue, orange

Alternatively you can build the whole array you need:

```
$styles = $data->groupBy('style')
    ->map(function ($styles) {
        return $styles->pluck('color');
    });

print_r($styles->toArray());

Array
(
[classy hat] => Array
    (
        [0] => red
        [1] => orange
        [2] => green
    )

[stylish hat] => Array
    (
        [0] => blue
        [1] => orange
    )
```

**Update to print**

```
foreach ($styles->toArray() as $style => $colors) {
    echo "<h1>" . $style . "</h1>";
    echo implode(', ', $colors) . "<br />";
}
```

**Update for blade view**

```
@foreach ($styles->toArray() as $style => $colors)
    <h1>{{ $style }}</h1>
    @foreach ($colors as $color)
        {{ $color }},
    @endforeach
    <!-- OR -->
    {{ implode(', ', $colors) }} 
@endforeach
```

Comment: In your second example, the code looks really clean but how can I output the name of the array as the header as you did in the first example?  Same way?

Comment: Essentially the same way, except in the second example you only have the colors. So you could just implode the ```$colors``` or loop over them if you want. I updated to reflect the printing.

Comment: having issue with the implode and echo since laravel blade doesnt recognize standard php.  I need to use the {{ $variable }} syntax and I'm having an issue figuring out how to incorporate this implode with blade.

Comment: ```{{ implode(', ', $colors) }}``` should work fine. Alternatively just loop over the colors using a foreach as well, so ```@foreach ($colors as $color) {{ $color }} @endforeach```

Comment: laravel blade DOES recognize standard PHP btw. <?php ?> work just fine

Comment: Thank you Leon, that was a great code example and exactly what I needed!